# Backbone Collection - Model Update

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

I retrieve a list of models from server into a collection. When a user is interested in a specific model, I route it to a viewer for that model based on the id.

Now, let's say a user need edits to that model in the view - eg: he updates his name. I set the url of the model, update the name and call save. It calls the backend (Jersey in my case) and it gets saved. However, the collection is still not updated automatically.

Why cannot a collection bind to each change in the model and update it self?

What is the correct way of saving a model which is a part of the collection? Is it right to call save on a model (by setting its url) and then remove from its parent collection and then add it again with silent:true?

Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't have to set the url, the model gets its url from the collection it belongs to (assuming you follow the recommended api format). What do you mean by "the collection is not updated automatically"? As long as you're using the model object that belongs to the collection, change events will fire when the model is saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The Collection is not updated?

When you say *"the collection is not updated automatically"* I guess you mean *"the View is not updated automatically"*.

The View will not respond to Model changes at least you say so explicitly using *bindings*:

```
// code simplified and no tested
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var MyModelView = 
  Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
      this.model.on( "change:all", this.render, this );
    },
    render: function(){
      this.$el.html( "<h1>" + this.model.title + "</h1>" );
    }
  })
```

#### Declare the URL explicitly for each Model

As @OlliM has said, this shouldn't be necessary if your backend is supporting an standard CRUD API. You can declare the URL in your Collection like this:

- `/app/collection`

And Backbone will use this URLs as the API:

- (GET) `/app/collection` fetch the whole Collection
- (GET) `/app/collection/1` fetch only the Model with id = 1
- (PUT) `/app/collection/1` update the Model with id = 1
- (POST) `/app/collection` create a new Model
- ... DELETE and so on

Comment: I have bind on change event but somehow, it did not update. I will have to check the code. Thanks.

Comment: To be specefic, use `urlRoot` property instead of `url` for the Model and backbone will automatically use correct HTTP method and URL (as defined above) on call of `save` and `fetch` function